# Using demo DocuSign API with Slack

Tags: docusignapi, slack-api, docusignconnect

Could you tell me, how can I connect my DocuSign app in Slack with DocuSign eSignature using DocuSign API. Is it only possible with production API or I can do it with demo API?

Answer (score 0):

You've built a DocuSign app, and now you want to integrate it with Slack?

Go for it! It doesn't matter to Slack if you use the DocuSign developer environment (demo.docusign.net) for your API calls or not.

Remember that your app will call Slack (and vice-versa). Then your app will call DocuSign as appropriate for your use case and application.

Comment: I add a DocuSign application in Slack. In SharePoint Online I keep my documents and want to send them for signature directly to Slack. To connect them, I use an HTTP request (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes) and a DocuSign connector in Power Automate (Send envelope). However, the message for signature comes only to the mail, but not to Slack. So I thought, perhaps the DocuSign application in Slack does not work with the demo api.

Comment: If you're using a slack application written by DocuSign or someone else, you need to contact that application's author. For DocuSign, contact customer service.